# Where can one learn about dispersion relations for S-matrices?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Most textbooks on quantum field theory never mention dispersion relations at all. Where can one learn about dispersion relations for S-matrices?

Answer (score 2):

Bjorken  & Drell's QFT book. It is old but therefore strong on this point.